How to hold large sandstone tiles to cement wall while glue cures?
I'm walling behind my wood stove with sandstone - the first wall was a stud wall so I could sneak a screw between the gaps of the stones and into a stud. With a plate on the front, I could hold the sandstone blocks to the wall while the glue cured.
The next wall is concrete - the construction adhesive will hold once it's cured but getting the blocks to stay in place while the glue cures is another story. I can't easily sink a screw into the concrete.
My current idea for a solution is to just lean some very heavy things up against the wall. The wall is perfectly vertical so it shouldn't take much to keep them from falling, but I don't feel great about that solution.
Are there any other ideas for how to hold these things down?

Most people tile from the bottom up and use the combination of gravity and stiction from the thinset. Have you tried this approach and had a failure?

Yes - I'm using PL-premium (in theory it sets quicker than thinset). The slabs (tiles) weigh ~150 pounds each, so stiction alone won't do it

The sandstone at 150 lbs, I picture this is very large tile or is it thick natural stone?

Using PL (construction adhesive) is a mistake. Its "body" will not hold the tile like thinset does. Thinset is also a cementitious product, compatible with the base material. Set up 1 row a day, and you should not need any bracing if you mix the thinset properly according to the instructions.
Make absolutely sure the tiles are level, plumb and straight to each other by using long straight edges or tile clips that insure the surfaces line up with each other perfectly.
If your concrete wall if FLAT, not kind of flat, it needs to be flat,  then use a 1/2" notched trowel or larger to skim the wall and the tile before setting.
You could also use the dab install method where blobs of thinset are used, after both surfaces are tightly skimmed. This technique is used for walls that are not flat.

I agree with this answer.  PL is not the product to use.  There are modified thinsets that will " hold 1/4" steel plate to a ceiling."  as told to me by a tile expert.  if doubtful,  go to a tile store and ask for help choosing a thinset.

I think you've convinced me to switch to thinset. The one wall (sandstone over 2x4) is already up, but against the concrete, thinset is probably the way to go.

Careful, if you have the first course set with PL, that squeezes down to zero thickness. There is no way the faces will line up switching to thinset, which will take up at the minimum 1/4" to 1/2" depending upon the substrate.

@Jack they're on different walls (meeting with overlap on a 90 degree corner). The first round with thinset went much better than expected. I'm quote impressed with how sticky it is

I'm glad it's working for you. I need to add that you need to use a modified thinset. A non modified dries out too quickly, therefore weaker.

If you can afford the time, you can layer the stones. Do the bottom course, allow the thinset to cure. Put up the next stone with appropriate spacers below, lean something against the stone to keep it vertical.
